# Gridview Edit part

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview where when the user clicks on any row, it should take the user to the editpage with the existing data mentioned in the page.

So, my questions are

1. Do I have to make a new aspx page for the edit part ?
2. How to take the respective users with existing data in the new page.

Please refer my gridview code from my aspx page:-

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdUser"
            AllowPaging="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            OnDataBound="grdUser_DataBound"
            OnRowDeleting="grdUser_RowDeleting"
            OnPreRender="PreRenderGrid"
            runat="server"
            Width="100%"
            border="1"
            DataKeyNames="Id"
            PageSize="2"
            OnPageIndexChanging="grdUser_PageIndexChanging"
            EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false"
            CssClass="pagi">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDelete" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="UserName" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email Id" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="usertype" HeaderText="UserType" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" ItemStyle-Width="30" HeaderStyle-CssClass="k-grid td">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" AlternateText="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' CausesValidation="false" onClick=""  />
                    </ItemTemplate>

                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>   </Gridview>
```

Do let me know what can be done in order to achieve this. I have already written the update code. Just need help on the above two things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your questions :

1. Do I have to make a new aspx page for the edit part ?

   **Ans.** No, you don't really need a seperate page for editing, what you can do is give a command button in an extra column saying edit, clicking on which enables the text boxes bound to your data in the same page.
2. How to take the respective users existing data in the new page.

   **Ans.** If you really want to use another page, just use a link button something that can be added to a column using template field that redirects you to your modify page by passing some unique ID of the record in querystring. In your modify page, you read the querystring, fetch the id and retrieve data from database table based on the id.

something like this :

in your gridview add a field :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Modify">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypEdit" runat="server" NavigateUrl="" Text="Modify"></asp:HyperLink>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In you code behind in row databound event of gridvew

```
protected void grdUser_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            HyperLink Hyp = (HyperLink)e.Row.FindControl("hypEdit");
            Hyp.NavigateUrl = "~/ParentDir/youModifyPage.aspx?ID=" + ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblId")).Text; 
           //here lblID refers to a label field added in your gridview to hold ID,
           //I see you have already retrieved the id in an image button
        }

    }
```

make sure you include onrowdatabound in your gridview as `onrowdatabound="grdUser_RowDataBound"`

Comment: Codeek: I want to use another page for this part, as my senior wants that. So give some tips how to pass unique ID in query string. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, i applied the logic and it is working for me. I just need to clear the fields on Cancel click and redirect it to again the previous page.

Comment: why bother clearing all the fields on click of cancel if you are going to redirect to previous page. :P you can skip that part :)

Comment: ok man, thanks for the logic though.. :) Merry Christmas, enjoy..!!